# Is there a way to get child element of canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas

I have created a canvas element. Here I drag and drop Images from toolbar. Now I want to get Image, a position it with respect to mouse move event. But not able to get the Image. I just want to move image only when mouse is over the image, not when mouse is inside canvas boundary.

My code sample:

```
$scope.moves = function () {
    x = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
    canvas = x.getContext("2d");
    img = document.getElementById("gn");

    x.addEventListener("dragenter", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    x.addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    x.addEventListener("drop", droped, false);
};


function droped(e) {
    var xpos = e.clientX;
    var ypos = e.clientY;
    canvas.drawImage(img, xpos, ypos);
}


function moving(e) {
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, x.width, x.height);
    var xpos = e.clientX;
    var ypos = e.clientY;
    canvas.drawImage(img, xpos - 250, ypos - 250);
}
```

Comment: you can save image position and dimensions on canvas when you dropped them, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas 2d api draws in a so called "immediate mode". That means, the api does not keep track of painted shapes and objects. It will forget what it has painted right after it has been painted.

So you will have to keep track of the images on your own. You could do that with a list of *ImageModels* like so:

```
var images = [];
images[0] = {x: 100,
             y: 100,
             width : 300,
             height : 400,
             imageData};
```

You create an object like the one above for each image that has been dropped and painted on the canvas and add that to a list. After that you just need to iterate over the list *images* in your MouseListener and test if the current mouse-coordinates are within one of those images in the list. Then you can repaint the image at the new coordinates